# D3.json doesn't fetch data but no error

Tags: javascript, geojson, json, d3

I am trying to load a geojson file. I get an error (404) if the file doesn't exist but nothing happens if the file exists. I have tried different versions of D3 ... v3, v4, v5

```
console.log("hello"); // displays
d3.json("/sites/default/d3_files/json/conposcovidloc.geojson")
.then(function(data) {
   console.log("data"); // nothing
})
.catch(function(error) {
   console.log("error", error); // displays 404 error if file not found
});
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I just tested it with a json file (not geojson) and it displayed the console message.

Comment: Try changing *console.log("data");* into *console.log(data);*, without quotation marks?

Comment: Or also: *d3.json("...myfile.geojson", function(data) { console.log(data) });*

Comment: I tried with a different geojson file and it worked. I always add a comment to console but I removed it and it didn't display. Obviously there is something wrong with the geojson file but what?

Comment: have you run the  file through a GeoJSON validator  like GeoJSONLint ~ http://geojsonlint.com/

Comment: I did that ... using the Google Drive GeoJSON Map Viewer and it displayed correctly - no errors.

Comment: I've switched back to D3 v3 and can read the geojson file.

Comment: I have been able to process the file properly with v3. Not sure what the problem was. One possibility is that it took long to process and I did not realize it was still processing.